# SQL Server 2017 In-Memory _mod file missing

Tags: sql-server, in-memory-database, sql-server-2017

My client is migrating their databases from SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2017
by detaching their databases from the old SQL Server 2014 server and re-attaching them on the new SQL Server 2017 server.

The problem is one of their databases had the `Hekaton` In-memory optimization enabled and the `_mod` file was "accidentally" deleted. We are now unable to re-attach this database without it's `_mod` file. Worse, they don't have any backups of this database.

Has anyone had this issue? Is there any hope to recover the database, and if so, how can we do it? We have everything but the `_mod` file.

Comment: This post may get a better response on DevOps rather than Stackoverflow.

Comment: Why, oh why, were they doing it that way in the first place, and why did they not have backups...? I would suggest to give them something to shoot themselves in the foot with, but seems that they've done that already as well. I know hindsight is 20/20 but doing backups of your database is a fundamental process.